# R extract part of string

Tags: r, regex, string, bioinformatics, vcf-variant-call-format

I have a question about extracting a part of a string. For example I have a string like this:

```
a <- "DP=26;AN=2;DB=1;AC=1;MQ=56;MZ=0;ST=5:10,7:2;CQ=SYNONYMOUS_CODING;GN=NOC2L;PA=1^1:0.720&2^1:0"
```

I need to extract everything between `GN=` and `;`.So here it will be `NOC2L`.

Is that possible?

**Note:** This is `INFO` column form [VCF file format](http://www.internationalgenome.org/wiki/Analysis/Variant%20Call%20Format/vcf-variant-call-format-version-40/). GN is Gene Name, so we want to extract gene name from `INFO` column.

Comment: Question is a little unclear, as it seems your desired string will not always be followed by a semicolon.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Try this:

```
sub(".*?GN=(.*?);.*", "\\1", a)
# [1] "NOC2L"
```

Comment: Thank Kohske. And what if NOC2L is at the end of the line? then the hole line is selected!

Comment: How is your string exactly? Could you please provide an example?

Comment: like this: a <- "DP=26;AN=2;DB=1;AC=1;MQ=56;MZ=0;ST=5:10,7:2;CQ=SYNONYMOUS_CODING;GN=NOC2L

Comment: try this: `sub(".*?GN=(.*?)(;.*|$)", "\\1", a)`

Comment: Thanks for the question/answer. What if there is no such a thing in "a". In that case, I would like this to return NA. It doesn't in this shape. Any idea?

Answer (score 15):

Assuming semicolons separate your elements, and equals signs occur exclusively between key/value pairs, a non-strictly-regex method would be:

```
bits <- unlist(strsplit(a, ';'))
do.call(rbind, strsplit(bits, '='))

      [,1] [,2]               
 [1,] "DP" "26"               
 [2,] "AN" "2"                
 [3,] "DB" "1"                
 [4,] "AC" "1"                
 [5,] "MQ" "56"               
 [6,] "MZ" "0"                
 [7,] "ST" "5:10,7:2"         
 [8,] "CQ" "SYNONYMOUS_CODING"
 [9,] "GN" "NOC2L"            
[10,] "PA" "1^1:0.720&2^1:0"
```

Then it's just a matter of selecting the appropriate element.

Answer (score 3):

One way would be:

```
gsub(".+=(\\w+);.+", "\\1", a, perl=T)
```

I am sure there are more elegant ways to do it.

Answer (score 3):

```
a <- "DP=26;AN=2;DB=1;AC=1;MQ=56;MZ=0;ST=5:10,7:2;CQ=SYNONYMOUS_CODING;GN=NOC2L;PA=1^1:0.720&2^1:0"
m = regexpr("GN.*;",a)
substr(a,m+3,m+attr(m,"match.length")-2)
```

Answer (score 2):

As the string is coming from VCF file, we can use [VariantAnnotation](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/VariantAnnotation.html) package:

```
library(VariantAnnotation)

# read dummy VCF file
fl <- system.file("extdata", "chr22.vcf.gz", package="VariantAnnotation")
vcf <- readVcf(fl, "hg19")

# see first 5 variables for info column
info(vcf)[1:3, 1:5]
# DataFrame with 3 rows and 5 columns
#                  LDAF   AVGPOST       RSQ     ERATE     THETA
#             <numeric> <numeric> <numeric> <numeric> <numeric>
# rs7410291      0.3431    0.9890    0.9856     2e-03    0.0005
# rs147922003    0.0091    0.9963    0.8398     5e-04    0.0011
# rs114143073    0.0098    0.9891    0.5919     7e-04    0.0008

# Now extract one column, e.g.: LDAF
info(vcf)[1:3, "LDAF"]
# [1] 0.3431 0.0091 0.0098
```

In above example VCF object there is no "GN" column, but the idea is the same, so in your case, below should work:

```
# extract gene name
info(vcf)[, "GN"]
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to combining back references with `sub`, you could use a lookbehind and lookahead assertion with an extract operation, like so:

```
library(stringr)
a <- "DP=26;AN=2;DB=1;AC=1;MQ=56;MZ=0;ST=5:10,7:2;CQ=SYNONYMOUS_CODING;GN=NOC2L;PA=1^1:0.720&2^1:0"
str_extract(a, "(?<=GN=)[^;]*(?=;|$)")
# [1] NOC2L
```

Where:

- `(?<=GN=)` asserts `GN=` must be ahead of the match
- `(?=;|$)` asserts `;` or end of string (`$`) must be behind (after) the match
- `[^;]*` matches any number of characters that are not `;`

Note: `[^;]*` was used over `.*` since the latter could match  a `;` and continue matching until the end of string (`$`).