# R: Extract N characters after M regex matches in one string

Tags: regex, r

I'm having difficulties in extracting exactly N characters after all regex matches in one string. E.g. N=3, and regex match is an opening bracket "(", and may be paste an aux word in between if M >= 1.

```
x1 = "use actual (Mon 3)|(Tue 4)"
x2 = "use actual (Mon 10)"
x3 = "use actual"
```

Desired outputs are:

```
"Mon and Tue"
"Mon"
""
```

I started with `gsub( ".*\\(", "", c("use actual (Mon 3)|(Tue 4)"))` and then tried to follow [R extract part of string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9721052/r-extract-part-of-string) but got lost in `?` and wildcards. 
Thanks!

Comment: Suppose if there are three brackets, would that be `Mon and Tue and Wed`

Comment: Yes, exactly. Apriori number of matches is unknown

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
 library(stringr)
 sapply(str_extract_all(x, perl('(?<=\\()[A-Za-z]{3}')),
             paste, collapse=' and ')
 #[1] "Mon and Tue"         "Mon"                 ""                   
 #[4] "Mon and Tue and Wed" "Mon"
```

#### data

```
 x4 <- "use actual (Mon 3)|(Tue 4)|(Wed 5)"
 x5 <- "foo (Mond bar)"
 x <- c(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5)
```

Comment: Thank you! It works great! I'm not 100% following where N=3 characters is specified (in case I need arbitrary N after a match?)

Comment: @AlexeyFerapontov  I am extracting the  character elements `[A-Za-z]+` that comes after a `(` which is used in the lookaround to match.  So, it will extract all the cases that follow the pattern.

Comment: Is there a way to extract exactly 3 char? E.g. if string is `foo (Mond bar)` and I will still need only `Mon`?

Comment: @AlexeyFerapontov  I updated the post, Sorry I didn't read your earlier comment properly.

Comment: Ah, indeed `{3}` is the solution. Thank you again!