# Return number from string

Tags: r, regex

I'm trying to extract the "Number" of "Humans" in the string below, for example:

```
string <- c("ProjectObjectives|Objectives_NA, PublishDate|PublishDate_NA, DeploymentID|DeploymentID_NA, Species|Human|Gender|Female, Species|Cat|Number|1, Species|Human|Number|1, Species|Human|Position|Left")
```

The position of the text in the string will constantly change, so I need R to search the string and find "Species|Human|Number|" and return 1.

Apologies if this is a duplicate of another thread, but I've looked here ([extract a substring in R according to a pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17215789/extract-a-substring-in-r-according-to-a-pattern)) and here ([R extract part of string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9721052/r-extract-part-of-string)). But I'm not having any luck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a capturing approach - capture 1 or more digits (`\d+`) after the known substring (just escape the `|` symbols):

```
> string <- c("ProjectObjectives|Objectives_NA, PublishDate|PublishDate_NA, DeploymentID|DeploymentID_NA, Species|Human|Gender|Female, Species|Cat|Number|1, Species|Human|Number|1, Species|Human|Position|Left")
> pattern = "Species\\|Human\\|Number\\|(\\d+)"
> unlist(regmatches(string,regexec(pattern,string)))[2]
[1] "1"
```

A variation is to use a PCRE regex with `regmatches/regexpr`

```
> pattern="(?<=Species\\|Human\\|Number\\|)\\d+"
> regmatches(string,regexpr(pattern,string, perl=TRUE))
[1] "1"
```

Here, the left side context is put inside a non-consuming pattern, a positive lookbehind, `(?<=...)`.

The same functionality can be achieved with `\K` operator:

```
> pattern="Species\\|Human\\|Number\\|\\K\\d+"
> regmatches(string,regexpr(pattern,string, perl=TRUE))
[1] "1"
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way I can think of:

```
as.integer(gsub("^.+Species\\|Human\\|Number\\|(\\d+).+$", "\\1", string))
```

It will introduce NAs where there is no mention of Speces|Human|Number. Also, there will be artefacts if any of the strings is a number (but I assume that this won't be an issue)