# Extract just the number from string

Tags: r, regex, split, extract, sapply

How to extract just the number from the following dataframe.

```
last_run<-c('Last run 15 days ago','1st up after 126 days','Last run 21 days ago',
            'Last run 22 days ago','1st up after 177 days','1st up after 364 days')%>%
  as.data.frame()
```

The desired output is:

[image]

My attempt is:

```
new_df<-sapply(str_split(last_run$last_run," run"|"after"),'[',2)%>%
  as.data.frame()
```

Comment: Does [this previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41116310/return-number-from-string) answer your question?

Comment: similar to Ronak's answer, look ahead can be applied `as.numeric(str_extract(last_run$., '\\d+(?= days)'))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sapply(strsplit(last_run, " "), function(x) na.omit(as.numeric(x)))
```

---

### strsplit

It will parse `last_run` and returns a list where each element is a character vector with sentences split in words

```
> strsplit(last_run, " ")
[[1]]
[1] "Last" "run"  "15"   "days" "ago" 

[[2]]
[1] "1st"   "up"    "after" "126"   "days" 

[[3]]
[1] "Last" "run"  "21"   "days" "ago" 

[[4]]
[1] "Last" "run"  "22"   "days" "ago" 

[[5]]
[1] "1st"   "up"    "after" "177"   "days" 

[[6]]
[1] "1st"   "up"    "after" "364"   "days"
```

---

### as.numeric

It will try to convert words in numbers and returns `NA` if it is not possible

```
> as.numeric(strsplit(last_run, " ")[[1]])
[1] NA NA 15 NA NA
```

---

### na.omit

It will remove NA from vectors

```
na.omit(as.numeric(strsplit(last_run, " ")[[1]]))[[1]]
[1] 15
```

`na.omit` returns a list, and the vector without NA is the first element of the list (that is why, you need `[[1]]`)

---

### sapply

`sapply` applies a function on each element of a list and returns a vector

Answer (score 1):

You can take some help of regex. Extract the number which comes after the word `'run'` or `'after'`. Using base R `sub` :

```
as.numeric(sub('.*(run|after)\\s(\\d+).*', '\\2', last_run))
#[1]  15 126  21  22 177 364
```

Using `stringr::str_extract` :

```
as.numeric(stringr::str_extract(last_run, '(?<=(run|after)\\s)\\d+'))
```

**data**

```
last_run<-c('Last run 15 days ago','1st up after 126 days','Last run 21 days ago',
            'Last run 22 days ago','1st up after 177 days','1st up after 364 days')
```

Answer (score 1):

you can extract with a regex the values and add them to a data.frame :

```
run = c('Last run 15 days ago','1st up after 126 days','Last run 21 days ago',
  'Last run 22 days ago','1st up after 177 days','1st up after 364 days')

as.numeric(sub("(.* )([[:digit:]]+)( .*)", '\\2', run))
```

Answer (score 1):

In base R or in `stringr::str_extract`, put the pattern `\\d+` between border markers `\\b` in order not to catch strings like `"1st"`.

**1. base R**

```
gsub(".*(\\b\\d+\\b).*", "\\1", last_run)
#[1] "15"  "126" "21"  "22"  "177" "364"

as.integer(gsub(".*(\\b\\d+\\b).*", "\\1", last_run))
#[1]  15 126  21  22 177 364
```

---

**2. package `stringr`**

```
stringr::str_extract(last_run, "\\b\\d+\\b")
#[1] "15"  "126" "21"  "22"  "177" "364"

as.integer(stringr::str_extract(last_run, "\\b\\d+\\b"))
#[1]  15 126  21  22 177 364
```