# Write first letters of all words from a string into a new one

Tags: r

I have to write all first letters of a string with 9 words in a new string.
Is there a better way to do it than:

```
    eg <- "This is a test I developed"
    temp.eg <- strsplit(eg,' ')[[1]]
    temp.eg <- substr(temp.eg, 0, 1)
    new.eg <- paste(temp.eg, collapse = "")
```

Also, is there another way of splitting the string, so I dont have to use:

```
strsplit() [[1]]
```

Comment: Your solution looks good to me. What do you mean with "is there a better way"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9721052/r-extract-part-of-string

Answer (score 4):

You can use gsub to extract the first letter and words boundary (`\\b`):

```
gsub("\\b(\\w)(\\b|(\\w+))( |$)", "\\1", eg)
[1] "TiatId"
```

**Explanation:** you're asking for a "word" character (`\\w`) that comes after a word boundary and that is followed by either a word boundary or more word character then either a space or the end of the string (`$`).

---

***Another option given by @lukeA:***

```
gsub("(?<!\\b).|\\s", "", eg, perl=TRUE)
[1] "TiatId"
```

It uses look-behind (`?<!`: *before must not be...*) to "suppress" (replace by empty string) anything or a space which follows anything that is not a word boundary.

Answer (score 3):

To avoid `[[` subset we can use `unlist`, the rest of your code looks fine:

```
paste(substr(unlist(strsplit(eg, " ")), 1, 1), collapse = "")
# [1] "TiatId"
```

If we have more than one string:

```
egLong <- c("This is a test I developed", "another test me")

sapply(strsplit(egLong, " "), function(i){
  paste(substr(i, 1, 1), collapse = "")
  })
# [1] "TiatId" "atm"
```