# Parsing a string in r programming

Tags: r, parsing, gsub

I need to create a function in R that takes in a string:

```
f3("€1.220,36 €3.002,18")
```

and spits out:

```
1220.36 3002.18
```

Thanks.

Comment: Try `gsub(",", ".", gsub("[.€]", "", str1))# "1220.36 3002.18"`

Comment: @akrun what is str1 representing?

Comment: It is the string object created.

Comment: @akrun Thanks this worked except see my comment under your answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R extract part of string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9721052/r-extract-part-of-string)

Answer (score 3):

We can do this with two `gsub`s

```
gsub(",", ".", gsub("\x80|\\.", "", str1))
#[1] "1220.36 3002.18"
```

If we need to convert to numeric, wrap it with `scan`

```
scan(text=gsub(",", ".", gsub("\x80|\\.", "", str1)), what = numeric(), quiet = TRUE)
#[1] 1220.36 3002.18
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "€1.220,36 €3.002,18"
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked. Except, I have single quotes wrapping my result. How do I have the function remove those single quotes?

Comment: @skatofia  I didn't find any single quotes

Comment: Right now, I'm getting '1220.36 3002.18' instead of 1220.36 3002.18 in my output for my function

Comment: @skatofia  Do you want as two numeric values or a single string value?  If it is the former, then `scan(text=output, what = numeric())`

Comment: The numeric worked except then there is a 0 at the end of the string, it gets removed when I don't want it to. Ex: f3("€4.112,86 €2,30") becomes: 4112.86 2.3

Comment: how do I get the 0 to appear at the end?

Comment: @skatofia  Then you need to keep it as string because when it is converted to numeric, it removes the last 0

Comment: I came up with a solution just to see it's almost exactly what you wrote haha

Answer (score 2):

Another option using the stringr library:

```
 library(stringr)
 x <- "€1.220,36 €3.002,18"
 str_replace_all(x, c("€" = "", "\\." = "", "\\," = "."))

 [1] "1220.36 3002.18"
```